# Output is not been captured in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to capture the output in a variable but I am not able to do so. I tried below scenarios:

```
verify=$(su - omc -c "ldapsearch -x -n -D "uid=rac3gp,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net" -w hee_120" 2> /dev/null)
```

When I do echo $verify, it displays blank output

```
su - omc -c "ldapsearch -x -n -D "uid=rac3gp,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net" -w hee_120" >>dd.txt
```

The output is not captured in another file too. The expected output is

> ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

which should be displayed after successful execution.

Comment: @anubhava: What more info you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an error to me.

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

So this could be being printed to `stderr`? If you change the `2> /dev/null` to `2>&1` in your first attempt to store it in a variable then that should work.

Comment: verify=$(su - omc -c "ldapsearch -x -n -D "uid=rac3gp,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net" -w hee_120" 2&1> mm.txt) I tried this and its not working

Comment: @PrashantSingh `verify=$(su - omc -c "ldapsearch -x -n -D "uid=rac3gp,ou=people,ou=accounts,dc=netact,dc=net" -w hee_120" > mm.txt 2>&1)` You direct the stdout to a file then the `stderr` to the `stdout` :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, that's an error message. Error messages are typically written to the stderr.

So do a redirection before capturing: `2>&1` (and don't send it to `/dev/null`).